# Flag post if it is lengthy?

Tags: discussion, flags

I saw a Stack Overflow question called [What could hackers do to a website and how do you protect my website  from these attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030780/what-weapons-do-hackers-have-and-how-do-you-defend-against-each) (if it has not been flagged/deleted yet) which was interesting, but the post was way too long.

My question is: Should I flag a lengthy question, or should I just leave it alone? And if so, how long does it have to be to qualify?

Comment: Perhaps ask the OP if he can briefly summarize his question at the top, so the main point of the question can be understood without going through the whole post. Then if all the detail is truly needed he can expand on that below it. Just a thought.

Comment: That question wasn't really all that long at all. I'm not saying it was *short*, but... And the main problem with the question is it was too broad and kind of rambling. (which is tangentially related to the length)

Comment: Also, *this is just my opinion*, but please don't upvote such a question! You were thinking of *flagging* it, for heaven's sake. All you've managed to do there is encourage the behavior in the future.

Comment: What is the goal of the flag?  "Hey mods, check out this awesome long post!"?  Length shouldn't be a consideration when talking about quality.  If it was, we'd just shorten the max length of a post.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Length *alone* does not make a bad question. It can be an *indication* that the asker has not put in the work to reduce the problem to the minimal example (and if they're not prepared to put in the effort to ask properly, few people are going to be prepared to put in the effort to answer well); but sometimes questions do *have* to be long to be asked at all!

In the particular case you mention, however, the length wasn't the problem: the ['not constructive' / 'not a real question']-ness was, and now the necessary number of close-voters have acted on that. If you find an example where they haven't yet, by all means flag for one of those reasons.

Answer (score 10):

No, you don't have to flag posts just because they're long.  The system already flags posts automatically if they're beyond a certain length.

Comment: interesting - I didn't know that. What happens next? I would expect these posts go to review queue - am I right?

Comment: @gnat They go to the diamond moderator queue for review, but I don't know for sure where else they show up.  I'd guess they show up in the 10k review queue as well.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: *"I'd guess they show up in the 10k review queue as well"* -> Give the lottery a shot this week... you might guess right on that as well :).